# "Error 1962: No operating system found"

Tags: boot, system-installation

Brought a new Think Centre Edge 71 because

> The Lenovo ThinkCentre Edge71 desktop has been awarded the status of Certified for Ubuntu.

- [Source](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201112-10227/).

Spent the the past 2 days trying to get *any* Ubuntu 12.04 64bit to install and boot. All give me the same answer:

> Error 1962: No operating system found

Here are a few of the links I've tried:

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04. When booting, all I get is a black screen with cursor. Some of the links report to solve the problem. None have worked.

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1901748

Is there a relative simple way to install and boot Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on a Think Centre Edge 71?? I mean it is Certified for Ubuntu?

Comment: not an exact answr,bt u may concidr instalng 32bit version? And also,as per my knowledge,the 32bit r generaly the tested versions...your laptop must be certified for the 32bit version...though that doesnot mean 64bit cant b instald,bt just leting u knw abt the certification most probably being for 32bit...try installing it

Comment: Do you have EUFI BIOS? Maybe try traditional MBR setup...

Comment: @fleamour I agree, if you want to stick to (U)EFI, make yourself familiar with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI (states >=12.04.2 64bit as minimal requirement) or consider 14.04.1 which is the current LTS version with reliable (U)EFI support.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me on a thinkcenter.

http://fzakiul.wordpress.com/2012/06/11/install-ubuntu-12-04-lts-on-lenovo-ideapad-s205/

Things to note are that,

sda7 in that example is where linux is installed.

root (hd0,0) -> 0 means the first partition on hard disk. For me the second partition sda2 had ubuntu. So I used (hd0,1).

Happy ubuntu guys.